# Cygwin install include linux/ip.h

Tags: c, linux, package, include, cygwin

I want to write an linux program on windows and therefore I need for example the package `#include <linux/ip.h>`. I'm using CygWin64 but I don't know how to add the linux packages... unfortunately i couldn't find any solution online

I installed the util-linux package in cygwin but it didn't help

thanks for any help

Comment: Cygwin is not Linux.  Maybe install WSL2.

Comment: But it should be possible to compile on windows for linux...

Comment: For which functionality do you need `linux/ip.h` ? Are you sure that is not enough a POSIX header like `netinet/in.h` or similar ? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html

Comment: I want to write an linux program so i thought that i need also the linux library or am i wrong? Im trying now WSL2